# Domains and 'Private Registration Services'

Tags: domain, privacy

Last year i registered a few domains, with a 5th i could get free privacy which is what i wanted. My total was $43 for 5 domains and privacy.

Now i need to renew them. I have the cost of the 5 domains ($42) and 'Private Registration Services' which is 5*8 (another $40). WTF. I thought the privacy was on per account not per domain. I only need 2 domains so i can cut my cost vastly by just using the 2 + privacy on both. It seems stupid that i need to pay privacy per domain.

What are my options? Can i go through another company to keep my privacy information on all domains for a single price? Could i register the domains through another company to keep my price low? (Many of these are the same domain with a different TLD) What should i consider?

Answer (score 3):

"Domain Privacy" is a risky thing to engage in -- you don't actually own the domain and don't really have any rights to it if it's registered through a privacy service.  Although it's spruiking their own Privacy service, [Dynadot's QA on domain privacy services](http://www.dynadot.com/resource/article/qa.html?aid=0) spells out the problems with standard privacy services (you just have to ignore the "and so you should buy *ours* instead!" flourish at the end).

Comment: yikes, i dont own this!

Comment: imho, privacy registrations are an invention of the registars to create new revenue streams based on the assumption that the domain name purchaser is not smart enough to list administrative and technical contact info that won't open them up to identity theft. is it a real risk? yes. is it likely you'll have issues if you use some common sense when listing your contacts? no. is it a method geared toward generating more revenue, more than it being a method to protect the consumer? yes.

Comment: Testify, brother!

Answer (score 0):

Lots of companies provide the privacy feature free of cost. Paying for it seems crazy!

Comment: Can you name one that is trusted?