# I made a mistake? Domain, Privacy and registrar question

Tags: domain, domain-registrar, permissions, privacy

I had no idea but in this question I found out I do not own my domain if I use a private registration service [Domains and 'Private Registration Services'](https://serverfault.com/questions/82556/domains-and-private-registration-services/)

I have 2 sites I expect to get high traffic. I also don't want people calling my house and I prefer not to be known as the owner at the moment (I expect smart trolls on my forums).

I want to know what I should do now, I am worried if I try to register my domain later on that the price will be higher once the domain gets more hits. Is this a possibility or will it always be 7/8 dollars? I am worried if my domain gets traffic that the private registrars will sell it to the highest bidder. So how might I ensure it's mine so it isn't sold to someone who is not me?

Finally, the least of my worries is someone calling me at my house or mailing me junk by getting my info through the whois service. What should I do about that? I am thinking I should just renew the 2 or 3 domains I want and not use privacy.

Answer (score 1):

You are being paranoid. You have a receipt for purchasing a domain name, and you most likely purchased it from an ICANN accredited registrar, so you will be able to contact ICANN with that info if there is ever a problem, and a registrar attempts to steal your domain, though I don't recall something like this ever happening.

To add a sidenote to the above: if someone manages to log in to your account and e-mail, they may be able to steal your e-mail by moving it to another registrar. The move takes several hours, and even after the move, the domain can be moved back if you get in touch with your registrar and ICANN, I know this for a fact.

You still own the domain name, except the information on the whois is changed in order to protect your identity so people can't mail you spam and call you. The information is legitimate, and usually it's the contact info for the private registration provider that sold you the whois protection. A note: using false information can get you in trouble, and you will most likely be required to correct the information.

Registrars do not usually change prices, unless the costs for maintaining a domain name will increase for them, in which case you will have to pay more, but not by much, and everyone will be affected.

Always use a proper registrar like Namecheap, or if you really have to: Goddady.

Comment: Gekkz is totally right, you have nothing to fear here.  As for a registrar, I would highly recommend gandi.net.  They are a tad more expensive ($14 a year base price), but in my opinion, have far better service and their management interface rocks - not gaudy and designed for people who don't know what they are doing, but effective and powerful.